# Android min sdk requirements for playstore

Tags: android, sdk

I am a university student and need to make an android app that will work on Kitkat Android phones. Currently the min sdk is 21 but I need to change it to 19 to accommodate Kitkat phones. But doing some research I have found that sdk 19 is no longer supported on the Google Play services. So my understanding is that it is simply not possible or is my understanding incorrect and there is a way to do this?

The reason for this change to sdk 19 is to accommodate the phone versions of farmers who don't have the latest phones and android versions. (I am making an app for subsistence farmers)

I am using these sites for my references in case any one asks where I get my info from:
https://apilevels.com/
[https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-updates-for-kitkat.html#:~:text=As%20of%20July%202023%2C%20the,99](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/google-play-services-discontinuing-updates-for-kitkat.html#:%7E:text=As%20of%20July%202023%2C%20the,99).

In android studio I tried changing the min sdk level to 19 in the manifest, gradle as well as the project structure. It resulted in countless building errors.

Answer (score 0):

Google discontinued support for KitKat, but that doesn't mean that the Google Play services do not work on it. Cutting support means it won't receive any more updates, given how few phones that use KitKat nowadays are.

However, Google cares more about your `targetSdk` especially if you're willing to [upload your app to the play store](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk). As of August 2023, it needs to target at least API-33. Google Play store does NOT care about your minSdk version. Many open-source apps such as [Briar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.briarproject.briar.android&hl=en&gl=US) still support KitKat, it is uploaded to the store just fine.

Keep in mind that you need some additional libraries such as the "multi-dex" library which will make your build compatible with SDKs lower than 21 (Lollipop). Any app that has minSdk lower than 19 needs to implement multidex library. The guide can be found here: [Multidex support](https://developer.android.com/build/multidex)

Other than that, if there are any other build errors that you're encountering, please edit your post accordingly. Android Studio (including the stable, beta, or canary builds) should be able to support any minSdk version even KitKat, so I assume you need to work on fixing your gradle files until you get rid of errors. Once your build becomes error-free, don't worry about your minSdk anymore.

Make sure you use AndroidX libraries for maximum backward-compatibility. Such as AndroidX's appcompat and AndroidX's core libraries. This will ensure optimal consistency in behavior across all Android versions (as long as you implement the Compat code of those libraries). Anything with "[androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)" in it means it supports backward compatibility.